# AChartEngine: The relationship between mBarSpacing and mBarWidth

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm trying to understand how exactly is mBarSpacing influencing the width of the bars. At first glance I can see that they're in an inversely proportional relationship. Each increase in mBarSpacing corresponds to a decrease in the width of the bars.

Where in the source code is this relationship, between the values, handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bar spacing parameter is a coefficient of spacing between the bars. As far as I remember, the spacing is bigger and the width of the bars decreases once the spacing value gets bigger.

The bar width was basically added such as this can be controlled especially in the case when there is only one bar into a series. It is not recommended to be used in other situations.

See the `BarChart` class for extra information [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/src/org/achartengine/chart/BarChart.java).

Comment: Thanks, I have been checking that class. I know there's no free lunch in dev. but can you point me to the piece/pieces of code handling that part?

Comment: What is the exact part you are looking for?

Comment: The part handling the spacing/width relationship... or at least the width.

Comment: Search for the getBarWidth() and getBarSpacing() usage in the BarChart class.